# MYSQL: How to Select all columns and hash them with SHA2

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sha2

I want to write a SELECT query in MYSQL that will return all the columns hashed. I'm using SHA2 for the hashing. It works when I give, in parameter, all the names of the columns but I don't know the exact names of every column so I'm trying to make it work by giving * in the parameter. But I get a syntax error. Is there any way to do it without specifying the column names?

```
SELECT SHA2(CONCAT(*), 256) from mytable;
```

Comment: Create a query string using `information_schema`, utilizing `Group_concat()`. Now you can use that query string to do your thing.

Comment: Topicstarter what is your goal as MySQL supports native [CHECKSUM TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checksum-table.html)